# What is the best bitcoin software wallet where I can import my mnemonic seed phrase?

Tags: wallet, mnemonic-seed, seed

I have BTC mnemonic seed phrase and I want to import to my wallet.
I'm not a fan of online bitcoin wallets, and I want to install a software wallet.

What is the best software wallet for this?
I'm not sure but can I import the BTC mnemonic seed phrase to MetaMask?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

MetaMask ist not a bitcoin wallet, but almost all wallets use BIP-39 mnemonic phrases. You *can* import a (12 word) mnemonic in MetaMask, but you *cannot* use MetaMask to send or receive bitcoin.

You should also be mindful where you import your mnemonic. Browser based wallets such as MetaMask are naturally not as secure as wallets natively installed on your system.

There is no "best software wallet" as this question is completely subjective. My *recommendations* would be [Sparrow Wallet](https://sparrowwallet.com) (Desktop) or if you are looking for a more beginner friendly mobile wallet check out [BlueWallet](https://bluewallet.io). The latter will make it easier for you to "find" your bitcoin if you do not know what derivation path or script type you used.

Answer (score 0):

Never digitise your Seed Recovery information, except to a hardware wallet or other dedicated airgapped device. Certainly never on anything capable of connecting to the internet.

Etched onto steel plates, stored in multiple secure locations far from home, secure passphrase separately from 24-word mnemonic.

The HWW is irrelevant if lost or stolen NP.